How do I use three-legged Oauth1 protocol to reach the Schoology API?
I have a student Schoology account and I have acquired a consumer token and secret for Schoology's API, which I can confirm work for two-legged Oauth1 (tested on Postman). However, I am unable to make it work for three-legged Oauth1 authentication in Flutter, and I'm concerned this is either because I have a student account or my Oauth1 authentication flow is wrong.
More specifically, when I say "not working" I mean that I keep receiving the error: "Bad state: " and my code does not print my inbox messages as intended (again, this part worked fine in two-legged Oauth1 in Postman).
I'm using the Oauth1 Dart package as the import statement says:
import 'package:oauth1/oauth1.dart' as oauth1;
When the user clicks a button, the following function is called. Please keep in mind this is merely test code - I would not generally hard code tokens/secrets or use the print() method in production code, etc.
Function called:
void stepOne() {
    final oauth1.Platform platform = oauth1.Platform(
        'https://api.schoology.com/v1/oauth/request_token',
        'https://api.schoology.com/v1/oauth/authorize',
        'https://api.schoology.com/v1/oauth/access_token',
        oauth1.SignatureMethods.hmacSha1
    );
    //define consumer key and secret (in my actual code both are obviously included)
    const String consK = "--CENSORED--";
    const String consS = "--CENSORED--";

    final oauth1.ClientCredentials clientCredentials = oauth1.ClientCredentials(consK, consS);
    final oauth1.Authorization auth = oauth1.Authorization(clientCredentials, platform);

    // request temporary credentials
    auth.requestTemporaryCredentials('oob').then((res) {
      // redirect to authorization page
      print('Open with your browser: ${auth.getResourceOwnerAuthorizationURI(res.credentials.token)}');

      // get verifier (PIN)
      stdout.write('PIN: ');
      String verifier = stdin.readLineSync() ?? '';

      // request token credentials (access tokens)
      return auth.requestTokenCredentials(res.credentials, verifier);
    }).then((res) {
      // you've got token credentials
      // create Client object
      final oauth1.Client client = oauth1.Client(
          platform.signatureMethod,
          clientCredentials,
          res.credentials
      );

      // now you can access protected resources via client
      client.get(Uri.parse('https://api.schoology.com/v1/messages/inbox')).then((res) {
        print('API Response: ${res.body}');
      });

      // You can get optional values from AuthorizationResponse object if needed
      // print('Your screen name is ${res.optionalParameters['screen_name']}');
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error during OAuth process: $error');
    });
  }

I would really appreciate help from anyone with experience using Oauth 1 or the Schoology API. Thank you!

I determined the problematic line is auth.requestTemporaryCredentials('oob').then((res)...
Would anyone know what this might indicate? Looking for literally anything that might help me debug, even if it's not dart-specific.
